# MS SQL How to avoid loops when allocating amounts

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm building a system that needs to automatically allocate amounts to a `Charge_Detail` table.

I have the following tables:

```
-- a list of charges that are outstanding
DECLARE Charge_Master TABLE
(   ID             INT NOT NULL,           
    CompanyID      VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, 
    EntryDate      SMALLDATETIME, 
    Ref            VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Amount         DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL
)   

-- directly linked to master table to represent charges paid in detail
DECLARE Charge_Detail TABLE
(   ID                INT NOT NULL,           
    Charge_MasterID   INT NOT NULL,            --Foreign Key 
    EntryDate         SMALLDATETIME,
    Ref               VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Amount            DECIMAL(12,2) NOT NULL

)     

INSERT Charge_Master
VALUES  ('ABC123', '01/01/2018', 'INV-111', 25),                 
        ('ABC123', '21/03/2018', 'INV-222', 30),                  
        ('ABC123', '11/05/2018', 'INV-333', 15)
```

The objective is to have a query take the following parameters:

- `CompanyId`    e.g. 'ABC123'
- `Amount`       e.g.  45
- `Ref`          e.g.  'REF-142'

Based on the parameters it should work out the records that need to be `INSERTED` into the `Charge_Detail` table and the associated `Charge_MasterID`.

```
Example:

If the total amount to allocate is 45 against CompanyId: ABC123
then this is the Expected output inserted into the Charge_Detail table.

/* Charge_Master Table
 *
 *  ID     CompanyID    EntryDate      Ref      Amount
 *  1        ABC123     01/01/2018   INV-111      25
 *  2        ABC123     21/03/2018   INV-222      30
 *  3        ABC123     11/05/2018   INV-333      15
 */

/* Charge_Detail Table
 *
 *  ID  Charge_MasterID     EntryDate      Ref      Amount
 *  1         1             12/08/2018   REF-142      25
 *  2         2             12/08/2018   REF-142      20  -- cannot fully allocate therefore 10 still remaining to be allocated for next time
 */
```

What's the best approach with this? Would a CTE help? I'm not too familiar with them but I have tried a `SELECT` query with subqueries and case statement but I can't get it to decrement the amount remaining without using a loop.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Where does the 20 come from the the last example? The matching row in `charge_master` has an amount of 30.

Comment: Why amount is 25+20 not 15+15+15???? Is there a rule to combine only 2 rows? what if there will be still more than one choice?

Comment: I was using the example parameters so the total amount to allocate is 45. Therefore in the detail the first line to allocate is 25 and the second can only allocate 20 of the 30 in the master table.

Comment: It looks to me that the data for Charge_detail is given manually so it's not clear what you want here. Can you give an example with master data, manually given detail data and expected output.

Comment: I added a bit more information to make it clearer hopefully. The last part shows example of a `Master` and depending on the parameters given it should allocate the `Detail` as much as possible

Comment: @SlavaMurygin It should always seek to fully allocate as much as possible before moving to the next record. But if we were to give parameters of 15, then another 15 and another 15 then it would create a different output in the `charge_detail` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
DECLARE @CompanyID VARCHAR(6) = 'ABC123', 
    @Ref VARCHAR(30) = 'REF-142',
    @Amount DECIMAL(12,2) = 45

;WITH cte as (
    SELECT *, SUM (Amount) OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RunningAmount
    FROM Charge_Master
    ), Limits as (
    SELECT TopRow = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM CTE WHERE RunningAmount > @Amount),
        LastRow = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM CTE WHERE RunningAmount < @Amount))
SELECT c.ID, c.EntryDate, @Ref, c.Amount
FROM Limits as l INNER JOIN cte as c ON c.ID < l.TopRow
UNION ALL
SELECT c2.ID, c2.EntryDate, @Ref, @Amount-c1.RunningAmount
FROM Limits as l 
INNER JOIN cte as c1 ON c1.ID = l.LastRow
INNER JOIN cte as c2 ON c2.ID = l.TopRow
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: As the second step in that transaction you have to delete rows from Charge_Master and subtract from the last if it is not zero. You have to figure out how to do it.